# Windows gui C build system in sublime text

Tags: c, windows, sublimetext3

I had linker error: undefined reference to windows.h functions like textout,selectobject,beginpaint. But I was able to remove the error 
by adding `"-mwindows"` in sublime build system. But now im not able to get any output in windows terminal. Eg: if i try to use `printf("test");` it won't show any output in windows terminal and `textout()` will only output textout string in gui window.

I tried it with codeblocks and it was able to get output of printf in windows terminal and textout in another window.

Is there anyway i can make sublime build system do the same?

```
{
"cmd": ["gcc", "-Wall","-mwindows","-pedantic-errors", "$file_name","-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k" , "$file_base_name"],
"selector": "source.c",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"shell": true
}
```

Comment: This "solution" doesn't make sense, these subsystems are mutually exclusive. Remove `-mwindows`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build a console application, then you need to also add the `-mconsole` option to your compiler command line.

That will give you a Windows application that automatically creates and runs in the context of a console (text-based environment).

If you just pass `-mwindows`, then you get a standard Windows application that expects to have a GUI. You (your code) is responsible for creating a window and outputting text/graphics to that window. It doesn't happen automatically.